# Many to Many using LinqKit with EF Core with Generic class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm currently converting an EF project to EF Core but I don't know how or whether it is possible to:

a) Use `LinqKit` on Many-To-Many with EF Core

b) Use a) with a Generic class

I'm currently using the following class:

```
    protected virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryable(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = null,
        bool isCollection = false,
        int? skip = null,
        int? take = null)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = this.Context.Set<TEntity>();

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.AsExpandable().Where(filter);
        }

        if (includeProperties != null)
        {
            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            query = orderBy(query);
        }

        if (skip.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Skip(skip.Value);
        }

        if (take.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Take(take.Value);
        }

        return query;
    }
```

In EF 6, I would set the type of my generic class to a main Entity I wanted to deal with and if it had a many to many, I would simply set the IncludeProperties to the child Entity.

For example:

```
var test = GetQueryable<Company>(null, "Users");
```

This would returns all companies and return all the users associated with each relevant company.

LinqKit would then come in to add additional filters, orders, etc...

But I cannot figure out how to use this with a Many to Many relation in EF Core.

I've seen an example where you do something similar to this:

```
this.Context.Companies.Include("CompanyUsers")
                      .ThenInclude("Users")
                      .ToListAsynch()
```

And the above looks like what I need but I need to use it to be generic and I need to apply filters with LinqKit or some other way but I need to set filters, sorting, paging, etc... dynamically.

Any ideas?

Thanks

**UPDATE-1:**

My many-to-many relation class is defined as follows:

```
public class CompanyUsers
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

The reason I'm adding this is that while my table of users is called "Users" the navigation property is called User and as suggested by Dennis, I should specify the Many-To-Many class (CompanyUsers) followed by the navigation property (User) so rather than being:

```
var test = GetQueryable<Company>(null, "CompanyUsers.Users");
```

it should be defined as instead:

```
var test = GetQueryable<Company>(null, "CompanyUsers.User");
```

Note the `s` was removed to match the navigation property rather than the table.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use the string-based overload on Include like so:  `var test = GetQueryable<Company>(null, "CompanyUsers.Users");`

Comment: @Dennis1679 interesting... Never thought of that. Can't try it now but will be back in a few days and will update you then. Thanks

Comment: @Dennis1679 That worked. Once done, I just have to re-jiggle my AutoMapper  profile use the collection from CompanyUsers and map its User navigation property to the collection of User (model) when converting from Entity to Model. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, will you create this as an answer to make it more formal, so I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: There you go @Thierry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use the string overload of the [Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-3.1).*

```cs
var test = GetQueryable<Company>(null, "CompanyUsers.User");
```

*I don't recommend using magic strings. You should consider writing an method that returns this based on the models properties.

Comment: Additional points to your answer: 1) Change the way I use LinqKit as you suggested and b) Use the Many-To-Many class as part of the navigation which I didn't know you could do. As for the magic string, absolutely. This is me trying to figure this out first without additional complexities. Thanks again.